# "Save to Drive" Button not working in Mozilla and Edge browser but working good in chrome

Tags: google-drive-api

I have used the "Save to drive" Button from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/savetodrive and it working good in chrome but Mozilla and IE (Version 84.0.522.63) not working in below way :-
When i hit save-to-drive button and it show the popup to login and when i done login to gmail and click on save button in popup, then is close but file is not save in drive. Again the button ask me to login.
I have cleared cookies and cache also but it didn't workout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any type of errors in Firefox or IE? Inspect the console and see if there are any

Answer (score 0):

It seems your session is not stored.
Do you have data in your sessionStorage?
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/sessionstorage

Also, does your HTML document has a `<!doctype html>` on top and is IE rendering in standards mode?

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` after `<head>`, as per the manual you've linked in your post.